# Storing secret session data with Nuxt.js

Tags: session, nuxt.js

I am running a Nuxt app deployed in Heroku that has an Express backend that is used as a proxy and where I store sensitive data such as API keys as environment variables so that they are not accessible to the client.

Authentication is done through AWS Cognito and if successful, I add user details such as name, company, cognito groups to the Nuxt session. This is all easily accessible and editable from the browser, which creates some risks.

Without adding any additional infrastructure, is there a simple way to store session data in the backend so that it is inaccessible to the user? If there is no good way to do this, I am happy to consider using something like `redis`.

Here is the `auth` block in `nuxt.config.js`

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        token: {
          property: "access_token",
          type: "Bearer"
        },
        endpoints: {
          user: false,
        },
        clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        scope: ["email", "openid", "profile"]
      }
    },
```

And where I add session data on logging in:

```
this.$auth.$storage.setUniversal("user", {
   username: this.username,
   groups: response.signInUserSession.accessToken.payload['cognito:groups'] || [],
   companyId: companyId,
   companyName: name,
 }, true);
```